# Ubuntu boots only one time after installation

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, dell

I just purchased a dell inspiron 14 7000. I installed ubuntu 20.04 on it but I have a problem: Everything works fine during installation. I can boot it one time after the installation. After that, if I reboot it, it doesn't boots anymore: black screen.

First of all here is what I have done to install it:

- I put storage option from RAID to AHCI in the bios
- Secure boot is ON
- one EFI partition of 500 Mb mounted in /boot/efi
- One EXT4 partition mounted in /
- Ubuntu is my first boot option

Do you have an idea of where comes this problem from ? Why ubuntu boot only 1x after installation ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Disable Secure Boot to start with.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: Sometimes there a difference between 1. cold boot (shutdown, wait 10 seconds, boot) and 2. reboot because some cruft is surviving (and not cleared). - Please try cold boot. -- Next, please try Ubuntu 21.10, the newest version, it may work better in your computer --- Try also with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset` (if there is nvidia graphics).

Comment: @sudodus

Thank you for your suggestion. I tried with the boot option acpi=off, it worked. After downloading NVIDIA prioritary drivers it seems to work without disabling acpi.

Comment: @Poumon, I'm glad you found a solution and thanks for sharing it :-) Feel welcome to write an own answer (and I think after two days you can 'accept' it which helps other users find it).